# Makefile pattern rule with two or more dependencies %.sas7bdat: %.sas %.dat

Tags: makefile

I can't seem to find any examples of this online, and it doesn't seem to work for me. Can you have a pattern rule in a make file that has two matching dependencies?

For example

```
%.sas7bdat: %.sas %.dat
  # build %.sas7bdat using %.sas and %.dat
```

Specifically, if I run make, it states...

```
make: *** No rule to make target `sip84fp.sas7bdat', needed by `sipp84'.  Stop.
```

Even though the rule is clearly defined as above.

However, reducing the rule to this...

```
%.sas7bdat: %.sas
```

seems to work?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a `sip84fp.dat` file and it can't create one. Do you?

Comment: ahh, I was missing something further down the dependency chain (still pretty new at this make stuff). Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, both static pattern rules and implicit pattern rules can have multiple prerequisites that contain a `%` reference to the pattern stem.

Implicit pattern rules are different from static pattern rules, or ordinary non-pattern rules in that they only apply when they either have no prerequisites ("unconditionally make this thing") or else the prerequisites exist.

That is to say, if a target that needs to be built, like `sip84fp.sas7bdat` needs to be updated, then indeed the pattern rule `%.sas7bdat: %.sas %.dat` is a candidate. But a check is made: the `sip84fp` stem is inserted into the prerequisite patterns to generate `sip84fp.sas sip84fp.dat`. These both have to exist. If they do not exist, then the rule is removed from consideration, and the search continues for some other rule.

This is why in the end you get a message about "no rule": it really means that no rule was left after ignoring all the implicit rules that didn't apply.

By contrast, under a static pattern rule or ordinary rule, if a target matches a rule, and a prerequisite doesn't exist, the prerequisite must be updated. For instance if you have `foo.o: foo.c` and `foo.c` doesn't exist, the rule cannot be thrown away because it's not implicit: that rule must be used for `foo.o`. Make will then look for a rule which builds `foo.c` (and probably not find one: the error will then be that there is no rule to make `foo.c`, not `foo.o`).

See the topic [Implicit Rule Search Algorithm](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rule-Search) in the GNU Make Manual.

If it is an expected behavior that the `.dat` file might not exist, you have to express that in some other way. For instance, one way is to use some external dependency generation to make numerous concrete rules of the form:

```
foo.sas7bdat: foo.dat
```

Put that into a `foo.d` file, and `include` it into the `Makefile`. If you have a variable called `TARGETS` which holds the names of all `.sas7bdat` files, you can include all their `.d` dependency files like this:

```
-include $(patsubst %.sas7bdat,%.d,$(TARGETS))
```

This is the same as for compiling C. We wouldn't write a pattern rule like this for C programs:

```
%.o: %.c %.h
        # ... build steps
```

This is because not every `foo.c` has a `foo.h`, and so the rule would not apply to such cases. Rather, we have:

```
%.o: %.c
```

and then any additional dependencies, like `foo.o` depending on `foo.h` are expressed elsewhere. The implicit rule only matches the principal deliverables: the object file and the "root" file of the translation unit.

Comment: Thanks for such a thoughtful response!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I am getting the impression that make's dependency system is strictly linear, is that right? And maybe we can use a lot of filesystem state and recursive use of make to emulate creating multiple dependencies? I am not sure how to turn the even example into a situation where a pattern: `%.c: %.a %.b; widget  --a $(word 1, $^) --b $(word 2, $^) --out $@` that will make `%.a` target, and `%.b` targets if either is out of date or doesn't exist, instead of uselessly saying `make: *** No rule to make target.  Stop.`, I am ok with gnu-make specific tricks if necessary.TY
`